# TypeError: admin.listUsers is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed the following cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
  return admin.listUsers().then((userRecords: any) => {
    userRecords.users.forEach((user: any) => console.log(user.toJSON()));
    res.end('Retrieved all users successfully.');
  }).catch((error: any) => console.log('Request failed: ', error));
})
```

But whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: admin.listUsers is not a function
    at exports.getAllUsers.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/functions/lib/index.js:102:11)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:243:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

How do I resolve it? And how do I add a parameter to paginate my data, i.e. to get 100 users at a time or something? I am expecting to call the endpoint as follows: curl http://localhost:5000/sweltering-fire-5301/us-central1/getAllUsers. How would it look like with a parameter i.e. 'http://localhost:5000/sweltering-fire-5301/us-central1/getAllUsers?limit=5&page=2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imported the admin SDK like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
```

Then listUsers is available to you like this:

```
admin.auth().listUsers()
```

You might want to check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#listUsers), as they have everything you need to make this happen.

Comment: It's been imported, I followed the guide here: https://bigcodenerd.org/get-all-users-auth-firebase-cloud-functions/ to make the data available as an endpoint but with little success